# Making two commands access and modify the same variable

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I am writing a bot for Discord in javascript and I was wondering if it is possible for it to have multiple commands that change the same variable.
So, I have two commands `!addPoint` and `!subPoint`. I want `!addPoint` to `score++` and `!subPoint` to `score--`, but while having the var `score` declared somewhere that both functions can access it. Can this be done and how?

Comment: Yes it can be done

Comment: declaring a global variable `points` and creating two functions to add and subtract accordingly

Answer (score 1):

I feel like you lack some basic programming knowledge. Yes, this can be done.

```
var points = 0;

client.on("message", async message => {
  const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === "addPoint") {
    points += 1;
    return;
  } else if (command === "subPoint") {
    points -= 1;
    return;
  }
});
```

I would highly recommend learning a programming language, at least to a decent level before jumping into a more complex project such as this.

If you do want to learn a programming language, I would HIGHLY recommend a good book on the language of your choice. If books aren't your style, there are plenty of high quality tutorials for the basics on youtube. I would recommend either javascript or python for your first language. One massive point: Don't keep changing languages, stick with the same one, once you've truly got to a good level you can switch in a weekend.

- Javascript: [link to tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yQaAGmHNn9s&list=PL46F0A159EC02DF82)
- Python: [link to tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1Yd7upQsXY&list=PLBZBJbE_rGRWeh5mIBhD-hhDwSEDxogDg)